# How can I detect dead productions from an ANTLR4 grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have an ANTLR4 grammar containing a large number of productions I don't want to use.  I'd like to clean them out of the grammar file.  ANTLR4 doesn't seem to allow you to specify a "goal" symbol, but if it could, I'd like to identify and remove any productions that aren't reachable from that goal symbol.

Is there a way to identify these kinds of unused productions so I can remove them from the grammar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no such functionality in ANTLR itself. However, the ANTLR plugin for IntelliJ gives a warning when productions aren’t used:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Visual Studio Code along with my [antlr4-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) extension and enable code lenses (preferences: `antlr4.referencesCodeLens.enabled`). It will give you a reference count for each rule:

[image]

Or you can directly run `AntlrLanguageSupport.countReferences(fileName, symbol)` from the underlying [antlr4-graps](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-graps) library in a node shell. More API details in the [API doc file](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-graps/blob/master/api.md).